# transferring files using TCP

Tags: c#

I'm to trying to develop a program to transfer files using TCP (in a local network) with C#, files should be transfer in encrypted way.

My knowledge about c# is average, and about socket programming just know the basics.

Currently have no idea how to begin.It will be great if you have any suggestion about how to begin, if there is any book, website or any other resources.

Comment: Why?  Windows already does this.  Use TcpListener and TcpClient if this is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use WCF with netTcpBinding.

This would encrypt the file during transfer and reduce the development effort, since you do not need to program any low level sockets code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use it as a learning experience for C#/.NET socket programming, [there are](http://ftps.codeplex.com/) a [lot of](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx) [free FTP apis](http://ftplib.codeplex.com/) that will do it for you without the pain of having to reinvent the wheel. Indy has been going for almost a decade and the others are fairly stable.

Comment: yeah you are right its not a new technology:) but its just a small part of the program that i wane develop.

Answer (score 0):

TCP sockets are pretty easy to use. While I don't know the API in c#, it will undoubtedly support a send() method, where you can pass in the bytes of your file, and on the other side it will let you register a callback function that will be called when bytes are received. The TCP protocol guarantees that the data passed in-between will not be corrupted or lost. You will need to encrypt and decrypt the data yourself however.

The easiest way to begin is to code up a 2-client chat program where you send the messages using TCP. If you want to understand more about the TCP protocol and the "network stack" (a set of underlying protocols) then you can start on wikipedia and carry on with a decent book on networks - it is actually a very big topic, but you don't really need to know unless you are making a serious app.

By the way, an easy linux hack is to use netcat (type man nc to get help).